# Does voltage refer to conversion of PE to thermal energy?

Tags: electrostatics, voltage

just looking for some clarity.

Voltage refers to work done per unit charge between 2 points.

When there is no resistance (if a charge is flowing through a circuit with no resistance), there is no voltage.

So I'm wondering, under the assumption that to counter resistance thermal energy is produced, is the work done in a circuit only referring to the conversion of PE to thermal energy? If a circuit has no resistance, and a charge is flowing, wouldn't the flow of charge produce work in the conversion of PE to kinetic energy, yet no voltage would be present?

Comment: For the case of Thomson's thermoelectric effect $\delta q(T) = I^2 dR + I\sigma dT$ is the dissipation per unit time and unit length . If you integrate it over the conductor you get $q(T_1) - q(T_0) = I^2 R + I \int_{T_0}^{T_1} \sigma dT$ showing the energy balance in which $I^2R$ is the Joule heat and $I \int_{T_0}^{T_1} \sigma dT$ is the Thomson heat. Only the Joule heat depends on the electrostatic potential $V$ driving the $I$, here equal to $V=IR$ and measured by the voltmeter, the other is a diffusion term independent of the emf.

Comment: "Voltage" is simply the potential difference between two points. A priory, it has nothing to do with a "circuit", "resistance" or "flowing charges". Frankly speaking, I do not understand your question.

Comment: V= IR. 
no resistance means no voltage (for ohmic materials). Therefore voltage is linked to resistance in this context. My question was that when resistance exists, and electric potential energy is being converted (ie voltage is changing), is it only being converted to thermal energy or various other forms of energy.

@Hyperon

Comment: frankly speaking, you did not understand my question.

Answer (score 2):

> is the work done in a circuit only referring to the conversion of PE
> to thermal energy?

The work done by the field converts potential energy to kinetic energy while simultaneously kinetic energy is lost due to collisions between the electrons and the particles of the conductor, resulting in heating.

> If a circuit has no resistance, and a charge is flowing, wouldn't the
> flow of charge produce work in the conversion of PE to kinetic energy,
> yet no voltage would be present?

You can have voltage with no resistance. An example is the old cathode ray tube where voltage accelerates electrons in a vacuum (which essentially has zero resistance, in the sense that there is nothing to obstruct the flow of electrons) giving the electrons kinetic energy equal to the loss of potential energy. But, with the exception of superconductors and the thermoelectric effect, current doesn't exist without voltage as all conductors have some resistance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can have an electric current without a voltage, if you do not neglect thermoelectricity. Part of the electric current comes from a term $\sigma S \nabla T$, thus, as long as there is a thermal gradient and a non vanishing Seebeck coefficient, there is an associate electric current, regardless of the electrostatics potential (and of the electrochemical potential).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So Would a voltmeter measure the conversion of PE to KE between those 2 points? Or heat energy, or both? And if I were using a circuit to light a bulb, would the KE that is produced NOT be utilised in lighting the bulb?

I'm trying to reason with an understanding of just the basic concepts, so my apologies if the comment comes across as naive :)

Comment: A voltmeter measures the POTENTIAL for converting PE to KE. Remember you can have voltage without current.  As far as a light bulb is concerned, in the case of an incandescent bulb, the KE produced is converted to heat and light.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik Good point. See edit. Thanks

Comment: @hyportnex I was only giving an example of voltage with essentially zero resistance giving electrons KE, without getting into the details of CRTs.

Comment: @hyportnex I didn't intend to compare a vacuum with the ohmic resistance  but rather to provide an example where there is no obstruction to the flow of electrons. That's why I said "essentially" zero resistance.  I have added words to that effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The general question is not specific to voltage.

*Does **voltage** refer to conversion of PE to thermal energy? After all, if charges are free to move, we can't sustain a voltage, and if we consider resistive heating, then the electrical energy ultimately becomes thermal energy.*

*Does **pressure** refer to conversion of PE to thermal energy? After all, if boundaries are free to move, we can't sustain a pressure, and if we consider frictional damping, then the mechanical energy ultimately becomes thermal energy.*

*Does **stress** refer to conversion of PE to thermal energy? After all, if materials are free to deform, we can't sustain a stress, and if we consider mechanical hysteresis, then the elastic energy ultimately becomes thermal energy.*

*Does the **magnetic field** refer to conversion of PE to thermal energy? After all, if magnetic domains are free to move, we can't sustain a magnetic field, and if we consider damping losses, then the magnetic energy ultimately becomes thermal energy.*

Yes, this is all true. In cases of high mobility (of whatever process coordinate is of interest), it's difficult to sustain a gradient, and energy will tend to move down that gradient, generating entropy often associated with frictional heating.

However, this is because you assumed minimal impediment to system evolution and also assumed that damping is the predominant effect (i.e., that voltages can be applied only to resistors).

If I use a voltage to very slowly move a charge from a lower to a higher electrical potential at different heights, for instance, then minimal heat would be generated even while the gravitational potential is changing.

Thus, we can't generally say that all voltage does is convert potential energy to thermal energy; more broadly, it can be used to convert electrical energy to various other types of energy. Or, in the case of the unconnected ideal battery, say, it can be applied and do nothing, representing a driving force for the system to evolve in some way that isn't currently possible.

Comment: thanks a lot. Quite insightful. I'm just unsure of what you mean by "if charges are free to move, we cannot sustain voltage."

Comment: I'm aiming to paraphrase your question *"If a circuit has no resistance, and a charge is flowing...no voltage would be present?"*